# Url Manager hide controller name and function name in YII

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm new to the YII framework. I have to hide the default controller name and function name.
For example:

(Existing URL : http://localhost/food/store/home )

(Required URL : http://localhost/food/ )

In the YII framework config page, they have declared the `urlManager` as:

**URL Manage in config page :**

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules'=>array(           
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
    'showScriptName'=>false,
)
```

**Default Controller Declaration :**

```
'defaultController'=>'store'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create specific rules without using placeholders like `<controller>` or `<action>`, you just need to make sure you add them before the rules for the general cases.

```
'urlManager' => [
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        //Add the rules for the specific cases
        '' => 'store/home',

        // The general case rules go after the specific cases
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

use alias will slove the problem 
 `'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'rules' => array(
                'admin' => '/admin/default',
                'mobile' => '/mobile/default',                  'mobile/<alias:fees|aboutus|contactus|terms|policy|faq|aml|legal|news|testimonial>' => 'mobile/default/<alias>',
                '<alias:fees|about|contactus|terms|privacypolicy|faq|aml|legal>' => 'site/<alias>',
                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ),`